# Conflicts in R Shiny Between LDAvis and NetworkD3

Tags: r, shiny, lda, networkd3

Currently, I am using a tabsetpanel layout for my Shiny app with one tab showing the LDAvis plot and another tab showing the network plot.

However, the LDAvis (LDAvis library) plot disappear whenever I add forceNetworkOutput (from networkD3 library) in the same R Shiny code. I have tested this scenario in different combinations and the LDAvis plot will always disappear.

Both plots display perfectly in separate R codes.

Anyone encountered similar issues and resolved it? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that LDAvis uses a pre-d3v4 version of d3.js? If so, it’s probably because networkD3 uses a higher, incompatible version of d3 and shiny doesn’t currently have a way of managing multiple versions of the same dependency.

Comment: thank you. It seems like it. I will look in that direction.